# Yii2 cannot access Yii::$app from model

Tags: yii2

I am trying to access Yii::$app->user from model, but Yii2 cannot access Yii::$app from model. Is there any solution?

Comment: are you getting errors?

Comment: Using `Yii::$app->user` what kind of info you can try to get?

Comment: try printing out data: print_r(Yii::$app->user);

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter where you are trying access [Yii::$app](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#$app-detail) and its components such as `user`. Once Application object initialized during bootstrap you can access and modify its public properties from anywhere.

Note that in [Console application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-console-application.html) there is no `user` component.

If you are using [Web application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html), make sure you configure `user` component correctly.

Comment: Also, maybe he does not writes `use Yii;` at the top of the model file.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\Yii::$app
```

Or add following line after namespace;

```
use Yii;
```